# Cannot reach internal network on VPN

Tags: cisco-asa

So i have been configuring a ASA5510 to the best of my knowledge to allow VPN access(IPSEC connection) to our internal network and its resources. There is a alot of step-by-step guides and videos available which is what I used. AAA server is set up correctly.

When connected I am successfully getting an IP address from the VPN subnet but I can not reach any internal hosts(pings failing). Also I noticed that my default gateway is using a IP address from within the VPN subnet.

I have followed the wizard and configuration guide from online but am still in the dark...this is all a bit new to me!

I will post the config if you need to see it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here to do anything but guess.  And it's gonna take more than just the ASA config to figure out, I'll bet... still, it's a start, and better than nothing.

Comment: Q1) can you ping the default gateway?
Q2) can you show a log of the connection process?

Comment: First, reproduce the connection you are attempting in the packet tracer.  If that doesn't show you anything, turn on logging, and turn it all the way up, see if you can find the IP address of your VPN client in it (make sure you turn on / up logging for all firewall rules also)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd check the firewall rules ( what ports are allowed and not allowed ex: ssh ) I'd also look at the subnet if they are on two different subnet you may want to route it through or put them on the same